# Sublime Text 3 Shortcut Find and Replace won't work

Tags: sublimetext3, keyboard-shortcuts

I've found several topics related to my issue, but they didn't work. In Sublime Text 3, my macOS `super+alt+f` "find and replace shortcut" (raise the panel of find/replace) doesn't work. I already tried:

- running "FindKeyConflicts: All key conflicts":

  ```
  (super+l,alt+super+f)
       latex_fill_all                         LaTeXTools            
  [{"operand": "text.tex.latex", "operator": "equal", "key": "selector"}]
  ```
- an then put the following into Preference > Key Bindings (User):

  ```
  {"keys": ["super+alt+f"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "replace", "reverse": false}}
  ```

Comment: Try to revert ST to a [freshly installed state](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/revert.html) and then check if the key combo works.  If it does, then it's most probably some package that's not playing nice.

Comment: Hi, like I mentioned above, I'm convinced, the LaTeX Package did overwrite it. But this package I need and I do not know how to priotize this behaviour.

Comment: The LaTeXTools command is actually `super+l, alt+super+f`, meaning one has to hit `super+l`, release, then hit `alt+super+f`. This shouldn't affect the built-in Find and Replace command, but the only way to find out for sure is to either revert like @AshwinShenoy suggested or to disable LaTeXTools in your preferences and restart Sublime. If it does turn out to be this plugin, let us know and I can give you a way around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this answer will help if you run into the same issue, because it's a bit tricky. The issue is a small App I use which used the shortcut above.

It's clear there is a Shortcut I didn't find at start. With this information I just changed the following within Preferences > Key Bindings:

```
    {
     "keys": ["super+shift+alt+f"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "replace", "reverse": false}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to resolve your Sublime Text key binding conflict.

- Install the [BoundKeys](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/BoundKeys) package.
- Run `BoundKeys` by selecting `List bound keys` from the `Command Palette`.
- `BoundKeys` will create a new buffer (unsaved file) which lists all of your key bindings on a file by file basis, i.e. all the `.sublime-keymap` files that ST has loaded.
- Have a look at this [BoundKeys example output](https://gist.github.com/mattst/9ef94847f0ddaf67a1f0c3172c897471). The example has been heavily edited, enough so that you can easily see the essential components.
- The keys from each `.sublime-keymap` file are shown, with the highest precedence (highest priority) file at the top, while those from the file with the least precedence (lowest priority) are shown last.
- In the [example output](https://gist.github.com/mattst/9ef94847f0ddaf67a1f0c3172c897471) have a look at the bottom line in the top `.sublime-keymap` file, the `User` package. `shift+f10` has been assigned to the `context_menu` command, the right-hand column shows that there is a conflict with the `ChooseWindow` package. Look a little down and you'll see the corresponding line in the `ChooseWindow` package - the `shift+f10` line shows a conflict with `*User*`. The `*asterisks*` show that this key binding has been overwritten by the one in the `User` package.
- Now search your `BoundKeys` output for `Super+Alt+F`. You should be able to tell where the key conflict is and it should be fairly easy to see how to resolve the conflict.
- Note that you may have to search for `Alt+Super+F` as well. It should be clear that `Super+Alt+F` and `Alt+Super+F` are the same key binding but not the same text.

Comment: Hi mattst, thank you very much, for your detailed answer, I'm sure it will help other Sublime User. My Issue is related to macOS-Shortcuts and I solved it...